# Zurb Foundation 5: Have a non-clickable and non-hoverable text in top-bar, stylized as menu items

Tags: zurb-foundation

In this examle: http://jsfiddle.net/c8kp9119/ (depending on your screen size, it can be shown in mobile version, if so, resize the Result pane until the full version is shown), the "Just text" element should not trigger any actions, change cursor to pointer or be highlighted on hover. It should be just plain text block sitting there stylized as his neighbours. I.e. vertically centered, white text.

I didn't find an easy way to do this with built-in classes. The style seems to be explicitly associated with `a` elements only.

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are asking here?

Comment: I probably shoyuld've not use `css` tag at all, as I was writing my question with Foundation only on my mind. Does it make things a bit more clear after I added "Zurb Foundation" to the title?

Answer (score 0):

To do this you would need to write your own CSS.

If you are sure you want to use < a /> tags then you would need to add

```
.name a {
    cursor:default;
}
```

to your CSS file.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to do it Foundation-way and was hoping I can apply some class to a `span` or something to make it look like other items. I already removed `css` tag to make myself clear on this subject.